# Идентичны ли Java под Anroid и Java для пк

Tags: java, android

Интересует схожесть Java под Андроид и обычная, "ванильная".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Тот человек возможно имел ввиду, что "ванильная" (то есть обычная) Java и Java в Android это разные вещи. В общем это не так далеко от истины. Фокус здесь вот в чем:

1. С точки зрения синтаксиса Java везде одна и та же
2. Компиляторы тоже одинаковые
3. Дальше начинаются отличия, а именно:

   а) В Android реализованы не все стандартные библиотеки ванильной Java

   б) Кардинальное отличие: ванильная Java исполняется в стандартной виртуальной машине JVM, а Android исполняется в совершенно другой виртуальной машине Dalvik (в более поздней версии ART (Android RunTime), для которых применяются байткоды несовместимые с JVM - т.н. DEX байткоды.

Технически это работает так:

- Прогер пишет под чистую Java
- Далее компилирует обычным компилятором Java (`javac`)
- Далее система разработки (как правило в фоне и невидимо для программиста) полученный объектный код транслирует в объектный код Dalvik/ART (утилита `dx/d8` - [дока](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/d8)), присоединяет нужные библиотеки из Android API и все.

Поэтому с точки зрения программиста он пишет под Java, хотя технически это будет не совсем Java... (см. выше почему).

Answer (score 3):

В следующий раз требуйте пруфы. Вот например [офф доки пишут](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals?hl=en)

> Android apps can be written using Kotlin, Java, and C++ languages.

Kotlin - это та же самая java, только в профиль, а С++ полноценно можно использовать только прибегая к нативному интерфейсу Java. Конечно еще можно использовать языки, построенные поверх этих (например С# в unity, или javascript), но как андроиде ни пиши, все равно наткнешся на Java на каком-то уровне.